# Output result to a text file in vbs

Tags: vbscript

Please help to correct my code of which I need to get the result to show on screen and record it to a text file.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

MsgBox ConvertToKey(WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId"))
WScript.Echo "ConvertToKey(WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId"))" > C:\WindowsKey.txt

Function ConvertToKey(Key)
Const KeyOffset = 52
i = 28
Chars = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
Do
Cur = 0
x = 14
Do
Cur = Cur * 256
Cur = Key(x + KeyOffset) + Cur
Key(x + KeyOffset) = (Cur \ 24) And 255
Cur = Cur Mod 24
x = x -1
Loop While x >= 0
i = i -1
KeyOutput = Mid(Chars, Cur + 1, 1) & KeyOutput
If (((29 - i) Mod 6) = 0) And (i <> -1) Then
i = i -1
KeyOutput = "-" & KeyOutput
End If
Loop While i >= 0
ConvertToKey = KeyOutput
End Function
```

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. Edit the original instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's your script with corrections. Note the elimination of the `MsgBox` line, the correction of the `WScript.Echo` line (with the elimination of the non-VBScript redirection code) and the addition of proper indentation:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo ConvertToKey(WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId"))

Function ConvertToKey(Key)
  Const KeyOffset = 52
  i = 28
  Chars = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
  Do
    Cur = 0
    x = 14
    Do
      Cur = Cur * 256
      Cur = Key(x + KeyOffset) + Cur
      Key(x + KeyOffset) = (Cur \ 24) And 255
      Cur = Cur Mod 24
      x = x -1
    Loop While x >= 0
    i = i -1
    KeyOutput = Mid(Chars, Cur + 1, 1) & KeyOutput
    If (((29 - i) Mod 6) = 0) And (i <> -1) Then
      i = i -1
      KeyOutput = "-" & KeyOutput
    End If
  Loop While i >= 0
  ConvertToKey = KeyOutput
End Function
```

Now, instead of double-clicking the script, open a `Cmd` prompt and enter this command (change the script name to match your vbs file):

`cscript getkey.vbs>%temp%\WindowsKey.txt`

The redirection is a `Cmd` shell thing, not a VBScript thing.

Also note that the above saves the file to your `Temp` folder. You were trying to save to a file on the root of C:. That will result in an `accessed denied` error.

Alternatively, you can change the script to write directly to a file like this:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Key = ConvertToKey(WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId"))

Const ForWriting = 2
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Temp  = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
Set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(Temp & "\WindowsKey.txt",ForWriting,True)
oFile.Write Key
oFile.Close

WScript.Echo Key

Function ConvertToKey(Key)
  Const KeyOffset = 52
  i = 28
  Chars = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
  Do
    Cur = 0
    x = 14
    Do
      Cur = Cur * 256
      Cur = Key(x + KeyOffset) + Cur
      Key(x + KeyOffset) = (Cur \ 24) And 255
      Cur = Cur Mod 24
      x = x -1
    Loop While x >= 0
    i = i -1
    KeyOutput = Mid(Chars, Cur + 1, 1) & KeyOutput
    If (((29 - i) Mod 6) = 0) And (i <> -1) Then
      i = i -1
      KeyOutput = "-" & KeyOutput
    End If
  Loop While i >= 0
  ConvertToKey = KeyOutput
End Function
```

None of this is new and it's all covered in numerous other answers, some of which you were already pointed to. No doubt this question will be closed as a duplicate, but it seemed you needed a little extra help, so here it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your alternative works better.